# Dummy ouput No sound ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10

Tags: sound, 22.04, 22.10

I know there are a lot of posts with this topic and I have tried every solution I managed to find. I am not versed in Linux, so please forgive my ignorance and if this is not the right place to ask this question.
I have installed ubuntu 22.04 in a clean disk, alonside w11 in an omen 16 laptop. I have no trouble in w11 and the speakers work correctly. The trouble comes in Ubuntu, only having dummy output (in sound paramaters and pavucontrol). I managed to get HDMI/DisplayPort - Built-in-Audio adding
`options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file, following https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/ blog (none of the proposed solutions worked).
I upgraded to 22.10 and to kernel 5.19.0-31, previously having kernel 5.15.0.60.66, following another thread (did not save the link). Unfortunately, did not work either. All updates and upgrades are on date.

Here are some outputs of the system and audio

```
lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 51fc (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bc (rev 01)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [Geforce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
57:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5228 (rev 01)
58:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)

lspci -nnk | grep -A2 audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [103c:8a4c]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel


inxi -SMA

System:
  Host: ----  Kernel: 5.19.0-31-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME v: 43.1 Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: HP product: OMEN by HP Gaming Laptop 16-k0xxx v: N/A
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: HP model: 8A4C v: 36.35 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: AMI
    v: F.13 date: 12/12/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA104 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-31-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes

pacmd list-cards
1 card(s) available.
index: 0
name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
owner module: 7
properties:
    alsa.card = "1"
    alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
    alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0x86080000 irq 17"
    alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
    device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
    sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
    device.bus = "pci"
    device.vendor.id = "10de"
    device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
    device.product.id = "228b"
    device.product.name = "GA104 High Definition Audio Controller"
    device.string = "1"
    device.description = "GA104 High Definition Audio Controller"
    module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
    device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
profiles:
    output:hdmi-stereo: Sortida Digital Stereo (HDMI) (priority 5900, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround: Sortida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71: Sortida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) (priority 800, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Sortida Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Sortida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Sortida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Sortida Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Sortida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Sortida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Sortida Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) (priority 5700, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Sortida Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) (priority 600, available: no)
    output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Sortida Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) (priority 600, available: no)
    off: Inactiu (priority 0, available: unknown)
active profile: <off>
ports:
    hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"
    hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        properties:
            device.icon_name = "video-display"

pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
 index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estèreo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 11
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

alsamixer shows both devices (built-in HDA and HDA nvidia) opened, but they all show "This sound device does not have any capture controls".

I have no clue what to do and all  the proposed solutions I found do not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to fix it two days now. Again,  please forgive the ignorance, the newbie mistakes and the repost.
At your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**
Since your card is from Intel, try installing `firmware-sof-signed` and reboot, worked for my intel card.

**Too long; read anyway:**
I had the same problem for months, and same as you tried absolutely everything and nothing worked. I thought it was an Ubuntu 22.04 issue because I have another computer with 22.10 and audio worked fine. So I upgraded to 22.10, and did not work, tried a fresh 22.10 install and did not work either. I also tried different kernel versions and still nothing.

It happens that my two computers are a thinkpad x230 and a thinkpad t14, so I thought that maybe there was a problem with the soundcard driver so this is what I did:
run:

```
lspci -v | grep Audio
```

output:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS (prog-if 80)
```

Googled for the driver, and came across with this thread: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/comet-lake-pch-lp-cavs-sound-card-not-detected-after-latest-update/86232

Looked for the package for Ubuntu (`firmware-sof-signed`), and here is its description:
"Provides the Intel SOF audio firmware and topology needed for audio functionality on some Intel system."

Tried it and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I could not make it work. I also tried 5.16, 5.18 and 5.19 kernel versions, as proposed in another thread, but same Dummy output result. Interestingly, I tried a bootable Manjaro Plasma distro and the speakers worked right away. Same drivers and devices identified as in ubuntu, so I am completely lost on why it worked. I am thinking about installing it and leave ubuntu behind. Again, thank you and I will update in case I found a way to solve this issue.